# Copying files from the Phone to a PC

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any ways to copy text files (I already wrote some files using C#) from windows phone 7 to computer?

Comment: If you're only looking for a way to see your files on your device on your machine for debugging purposes, you should use the Isolated Storage Tool included in the 7.1 sdk. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions. Here is the exact thing that I was looking for. Hope that it would help others.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: note that it works only if an app has been sideloaded, not for apps installed from the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. I think you want to copy the txt files you generate on the device to a pc?

You can't do it because of restrictions on the device.. (you can use only your IsolatedStorage and nothing else (without unlocking the device))

you can send the content of the file via email or using skydrive for the transfer

Comment: email? I tried to attach files, however, it only shows the the available images? how to attach the written text file?

Comment: You cannot attach a file to an email from your application.

Comment: yes, I meant "copy the file content in the email body".. sorry for the misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 1):

[Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202874%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) are your best friends at this point, being the only link to your PC that is directly accessible through the SDK. You could also try working [with a service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202874%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is way to access your isolated storage files from the PC take a look [here](http://www.j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2010/08/24/Getting-to-my-Isolated-Files.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

You should give more details, what do you mean by copy ?

Do you just want to do some thing like   copy(TheFileToCopy, TheFileCreatedAsACopy) ?
In that case maybe look at the msnd doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx

or maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx

Does it helped you ?

Comment: well... I already wrote a file programmatically in the windows phone device, now I want to take that file to my computer.

Comment: None of the methods you showed work on a Windows Phone. The platform is much more restricted.

Comment: Well that's why i'm aking if it helped, it's no use saying what i said is useless... Anyway i saw something like that on James O'Neill's blog http://jamesone111.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/how-to-get-files-from-a-windows-phone-7-app-to-a-pc/

Comment: He is talking about a completely different thing. The methods you are referencing are targeting the full .NET Framework, not the WP SL\XNA combo.